# How to check and replace cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, if-this-then-that

I need help trying to figure this out. I am extremely new to formulas and very confused.

Here is my thought process:
IF B1 contains a comma AND C1 is exactly "none" THEN I want C1 to be replaced with "USA".

[image: Screenshot of my test sheet]

Do I need a new column to make this happen? or could I some how use Conditional formatting? I've really only used formulas in Conditional Formatting so I'm not sure where to start.

Here is the link to a spreadsheet if you need it
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cHtJg04BLrwvWBFaqy5VeSRJSjlA9qQcnNePZLI8u7M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following formula in cell `D3` (or anywhere else you may need to).

```
=IF(AND(REGEXMATCH(B3, ","),C3="none"), "USA","Oops")
```

*(Of course you can change `"Oops"` to whatever you like or even a blank cell`""`)*

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.